# Single Element Lists Have Same Head But Are Not Equal?

Tags: scala

Given two `List[A]` instances, under what circumstance could the following be true?

```
list.head == otherList.head // returns true
list.size == 1              // returns true
list.size == otherList.size // returns true
```

but

```
list == otherList // returns false
```

Comment: when the lists have same first item, same size, but otherwise are different? :)

Comment: good point - updated my question.

Comment: Inconsistent equality implementation based on mutable variables?

Comment: @Yuval - the `A` type does not have any mutable variables.

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE]? Or is this a theoretical question?

Comment: Perhaps if the iterators for these lists do not behave as expected, you might not pass the [`sameElements`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/05016d9035ab9b1c866bd9f12fdd0491f1ea0cbb/src/library/scala/collection/IterableLike.scala#L290-L298) check. But that's purely theoretical.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - I ran into this type of situation at work today. However, I failed, after a few attempts, to create a minimum example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I can cheat and use my own `A` then this would be an example:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class MyClass(val v: Int)
{
    def ==(that: MyClass): Boolean = true
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class MyClass

scala> val l1 = List(new MyClass(1))
l1: List[MyClass] = List(MyClass@36776c32)

scala> val l2 = List(new MyClass(2))
l2: List[MyClass] = List(MyClass@39c87b42)

scala> l1.head == l2.head
res4: Boolean = true

scala> l1.size == l2.size
res5: Boolean = true

scala> l1.size == 1
res6: Boolean = true

scala> l1 == l2
res7: Boolean = false
```

You don't even need mutable values for this, it is just a trick using my own `==` method. But this is intentionally malignant, hopefully nobody would write code which would do this.

**Edit:**

All you need to do is either a) trick/break `==` like I did with `MyClass` or, as @2rs2ts pointed out, trick/break the [`sameElements`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/05016d9035ab9b1c866bd9f12fdd0491f1ea0cbb/src/library/scala/collection/IterableLike.scala#L290-L298) check (which uses `!=`) :

```
def sameElements[B >: A](that: GenIterable[B]): Boolean = {
    val these = this.iterator
    val those = that.iterator
    while (these.hasNext && those.hasNext)
        if (these.next != those.next)
            return false
    !these.hasNext && !those.hasNext
}
```